# Quais classes implementam o tipo abstrato de dados fila?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Tendo em conta que existem as classes `java.util.Stack` e `java.util.ArrayDeque` no contexto das pilhas, também existem classes Java que implementam o tipo abstrato de dados fila?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.util.Queue` é uma interface que define a estrutura de dados Fila e umas das classes que implementam `Queue` é a `LinkedList`. Assim, a `LinkedList` é uma implementação de Fila.

Comment: E qual é a politicade crescimento de uma `LinkedList`?

Comment: http://ashkrit.blogspot.com.br/2015/09/collection-resize-and-merge-policy.html https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/data/Collection%20Variables.html